# How to add additional where clause in existing view

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have an exiting view and need to add additional where clause to it. I do not have privilieges to try and error on my oracle 11g. What is the best way to do this?

```
create view XYZ as
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
     FROM table_name
where column 1 in ('aa', 'bb');
```

I just want to update the view with additional value in where clause

```
SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
     FROM table_name
where column 1 in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc');
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What is the error you are getting?  Please edit your question to make this clear.

Comment: I am not getting any error. I am not able to try it as I have "Insufficient Privileges" to try this out.

Comment: Do I have to use Alter view command or 
create or replace view XYZ as 
SELECT coulmn1 , coulmn2 , coulmn3 , coulmn4
     FROM table_name
where column1 in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc'); would work ?

Comment: Then you must elevate your permissions (or get your database administrator to do it for you), using an administrator account

Comment: I have to just prepare the command give it to DBA to execute as I do not have permission. Just wanted to make sure I am giving right command to execute.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ALTER VIEW` only to define, modify, or drop view constraints.

To redefine a view, you must use `create or replace view`.

Construct a statement  with appropriate schema / owner names and ask a super-user or DBA to execute it if you do not have privileges.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW  schemaname.yourviewname AS
  SELECT column1, column2, column3, column4
     FROM schema_name.table_name
  where column_1 in ('aa', 'bb', 'cc');
```

Make sure you ask them to grant all the required privileges to be able to read from it, which I believe you should be having already.

Comment: Do I have to give commit as well in the script ? Is it required ?

Comment: @SnehalK : Not required, the ddl statements are auto-committed by default.